# CakePHP in nested folder with wrong routes

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, routes

I have cakePHP installed in `localhost/domains/mydomain/` and .htaccess file in `localhost/` containing following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /domains/mydomain/app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /domains/mydomain/app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

So my site is reachable on `localhost/` address. Problem is that all links on my website are pointing to `localhost/domains/mydomain/`. Is there a way that Cake would think it is in `localhost/` folder so I would get rid of the ugly `domains/mydomain/` in URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One year later I have found the right solution. Simply put this into core or bootstrap file and you are done.

```
Configure::write('App', array('base' => ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly nobody could answer my question so I had to use a workaround. To maybe help other generations, there is what I did:

I moved my webroot folder to the root folder of webserver:

```
webhost_root(localhost)
|- domains
|  |- mydomain
|     |- app
|     |- cake
|     |- plugins
|     |- vendors
|-webroot
```

And then I had to adjust webroot/index.php to look into domains/mydomain/app for my cake app:

```
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', (dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/domains/mydomain/');
}

if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', 'app/');
}
```

Only thing left is .htaccess in webhost_root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ webroot/    [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

Hope it helps someone.